# Не могу понять как и куда вставить функцию if

Tags: python

я недавно начал изучать python, сделал даже небольшую программу(её код предоставлен), но не могу разобраться как вставить функцию if. Я хочу, чтобы когда  из random.choice(cards) выпадает JOKER, то random.choice(icon) не выполнялась для него.

```
a1 = "2"
a2 = "3"
a3 = "4"
a4 = "5"
a5 = "6"
a6 = "7"
a7 = "8"
a8 = "9"
a9 = "10"
a10 = "Валет"
a11 = "Дама"
a12 = "Король"
a13 = "Туз"
a14 = "JOKER"
b1 = "♣"
b2 = "♦"
b3 = "♥"
b4 = "♠"

import random

cards = (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14)
icon = (b1, b2, b3, b4)

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Card Games")
window.geometry('400x300')
window["bg"] = "sea green"
lbl = Label(window, text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green",)
lbl.place(x=0, y=150)
lb = Label(window, text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green")
lb.place(x=0, y=80)
l = Label(window, text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green")
l.place(x=0, y=0)

def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), bg="sea green")
    lb.configure(text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), bg="sea green")
    l.configure(text=random.choice(cards)+random.choice(icon), bg="sea green")
btn = Button(window, text="Случайные карты", command=clicked, bg="medium sea green", activebackground="sea green")
btn.place(x=30, y=250)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Учтите, что у вас распределение жульническое:-) Джокеров в колоде - два (иногда один), а у вас - четыре.

Comment: If( //условие ): //условие выполняется
else: //Условие не выполняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

CARD = ("Валет", "Дама", "Король", "Туз", "JOKER",
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')
ICON = ("♣", "♦", "♥", "♠")

window = Tk()
window.title("Card Games")
window.geometry('400x300')
window["bg"] = "sea green"

def random_card():
    text = random.choice(CARD)
    if text != 'JOKER':
        return text + random.choice(ICON)
    else:
        return text

card_one = Label(window, text=random_card(), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green", )
card_one.place(x=0, y=150)
card_two = Label(window, text=random_card(), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green")
card_two.place(x=0, y=80)
card_three = Label(window, text=random_card(), font=("Comic Sans MS", 40), bg="sea green")
card_three.place(x=0, y=0)

def clicked():
    card_one.configure(text=random_card(), bg="sea green")
    card_two.configure(text=random_card(), bg="sea green")
    card_three.configure(text=random_card(), bg="sea green")

button = Button(window, text="Случайные карты", command=clicked, bg="medium sea green", activebackground="sea green")
button.place(x=30, y=250)
window.mainloop()
```

Немного изменил но суть таже, используй все import вверху модуля всегда, как бы так устроенно, и зачем так много переменных если можно уложить всё в одну,
старайся использовать переменные с описывающим именем, учи ООП от дублирования кода уйдёшь